# Error in data table: Item has no length? - R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a R script that contains a function, which I recieved in an answer for this question: [R: For loop nested in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481192/r-for-loop-nested-in-for-loop).

The script has been working fine on the first part of my data set, but I am now trying to use it on another part, which as far as I can tell, has the exact same format as the first, but for some reason I get an error when trying to use the script. I cannot figure out, what causes the error.

This is the script I am using:

```
require(data.table)

MappingTable_Calibrated = read.csv2(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
head(MappingTable_Calibrated)

#The data is sorted primarily after Scaffold number in ascending order, and secondarily after Cal_Startgen in ascending order.

MappingTable_Calibratedord = MappingTable_Calibrated[order(MappingTable_Calibrated$Scaffold, MappingTable_Calibrated$Cal_Startgen),]
head(MappingTable_Calibratedord)

dt <- data.table(MappingTable_Calibratedord, key = "Scaffold,Cal_Startgen")
head(dt)

# The following function creates pairs of loci for each scaffold.
# The function is a modified version of a function found retrieved from http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

fn = function(dtIn, id){

```
# Creates the object dtHead containing as many lines as in dtIn minus the last line)

dtHead = head(dtIn, n = nrow(dtIn) - 1)     

# The names of dtHead are appended with _a. paste0 short for: paste(x, sep="")

setnames(dtHead, paste0(colnames(dtHead), "_a")) 

# Creates the object dtTail containing as many lines as in dtIn minus the first line)

dtTail = tail(dtIn, n = nrow(dtIn) - 1)     

# The names of dtTail are appended with _b.

setnames(dtTail, paste0(colnames(dtTail), "_b")) 

# dtHead and dtTail are combined. Scaffold is defined as id. The blank column "Pairwise_Distance is added to the table.

cbind(dtHead, dtTail, Scaffold = id, Pairwise_Distance = 0) 

}

#The function is run on the data. .SDcols defines the rows to be included in the output.

output = dt[, fn(.SD, Scaffold), by = Scaffold, .SDcols = c("Name", "Startpos", "Endpos", "Rev", "Startgen", "Endgen", "Cal_Startgen", "Cal_Endgen", "Length")]
output = as.data.frame(output[, with = FALSE])
```

But when trying to create "output" I get the following error: 
    `Error in data.table(..., key = key(..1)) : Item 1 has no length. Provide at least one item (such as NA, NA_integer_etc) to be repeated to match the 2 rows in the longest column. Or, all columns can be 0 length, for insert()ing rows into.`

dt looks like this:

```
Name          Length Startpos Endpos Scaffold Startgen Endgen Rev Match Cal_Startgen Cal_Endgen
1: Locus_7173    144        0    144       34   101196 101340   1     1       101196     101340
2: Locus_133     110        0    110       34   223659 223776   1     1       223659     223776
3: Locus_2746    161        0     89       65   101415 101504   1     1       101415     101576
```

A full dput of "dt" can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3j4i04s2rg6b63h/AADkWG3OcsutTiSsyTl8L2Vda?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with tracking the data which cause the error by:

```
function(dtIn, id){
    dtHead = head(dtIn, n = nrow(dtIn) - 1)     
    setnames(dtHead, paste0(colnames(dtHead), "_a")) 
    dtTail = tail(dtIn, n = nrow(dtIn) - 1)     
    setnames(dtTail, paste0(colnames(dtTail), "_b")) 
    r <- tryCatch(cbind(dtHead, dtTail, Scaffold = id, Pairwise_Distance = 0), error = function(e) NULL)
    if(is.null(r)) browser()
    r
}
```

Then you can see you are trying to `cbind` elements of different nrow/length:

```
Browse[1]> dtHead
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 9 cols: Name_a,Startpos_a,Endpos_a,Rev_a,Startgen_a,Endgen_a...
Browse[1]> dtTail
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 9 cols: Name_b,Startpos_b,Endpos_b,Rev_b,Startgen_b,Endgen_b...
Browse[1]> id
[1] 76
Browse[1]> 0
[1] 0
```

Which is not allowed.
I recommend to put an `if(nrow(` or something similar and then add columns `id = integer(), Pairwise_Distance = numeric()` for nrow = 0 cases.

Comment: I am not completely sure, what the above shows me. What does the 76 id etc. actually tell me? I guess, what the ultimate qestion is, what in my actual data causes the problem?

Comment: the 76 values is not important. Important is it is non zero length value, and you are trying to `cbind` it to zero rows data.table. You cannot have data.table where some columns with have length=0 (all cols in your data.tables) while other will have length=1 (id variable).

Comment: Hello Hjalte, I am also getting the same error. Was it because of the data table or something else?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh because of your code did not handle the case when one data.table has 0 columns while other has non-zero columns